# How to prepare date for wpdb insert query

Tags: php, sql, insert, wordpress

it gives me a headache for past 24h so I need you help.

My scrape returns 2 arrays (test-case).

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[title] => Abacosun Instytut Urody 
[kategoria] => Salony kosmetyczne 
[adres] => 80-254 Gdańsk, Partyzantów 3 (Wrzeszcz) 
[phone] => 58 341-90-90 
[email] => kontakt@abacosungdansk.pl 
[www] => www.abacosungdansk.pl 
[desc] => Dystrybutor ) 

[1] => Array ( 
[title] => Mathias Hair Design 
[kategoria] => Fryzjerzy 
[adres] => 81-387 Gdynia, Antoniego Abrahama 74 
 [phone] => 533-328-555 
[email] => salon@mathiashairdesign.pl 
[www] => www.mathiashairdesign.pl 
[desc] => Instytut Kérastase Mathias )
```

No matter what I try I can't send "adres" to the databse. wpdb returns (bool)false and I can't squeez anything more out of it.

As the data is pretty much the same (the format at least) why it works for the second one but not for the first one and is there a way to somehow prepare data for INSERT query and I don't mean sanitazing/triming/exploding.

As always thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

The address entry contains special characters you should encode it with UTF-8 php has utf_encode method  check here http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Also make sure you wp table definition has character set to UTF-8